# Document sets losing their Welcome Page

Tags: 2013, document-set, welcome-page

We are using SharePoint 2013:

In our solution we have multiple content types as child content types of "Document Set". In some cases, which we cannot reproduce, the Document Set loses its Welcome Page. i.e. when you click on the Document Set's Title to open it, only a regular "Filem List View" appears, but the Welcome Page does not.

For some reason this doesn't affect all objects of the same content type, just some. We cannot figure out how to fix this.

Would you have any idea that can help debug and fix this?

Comment: I was wondering. How were those content types created? Interface? Code? Declarative feature? Does by any means the folder icon show signs of bug to - do the set still have the set icon or it is replaced by the folder one??

Comment: The content types are created (defined) via the Web frontend, no programming. And yes, sometimes they have the folder icon instead of the docset icon.

Comment: Then I am pretty sure that you are experiencing an infamous bug that manifest itself just the way you described (wrong icons and missing welcome pages). Problem is - I never had that bug on sets created from the interface: as far as I know the bug should be triggered by a corrupted set state, something that you can achieve only with an incorrect set creation process. I will try to see if I can find out something more accurate.

Comment: Still no official reference. Anyway, you could try the script posted on this blog. Doesn't provide a reason but it could provide a fix. [See Here](http://sharedpointers.blogspot.it/2013/04/fixing-folders-that-have-been-converted.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "Allow management of content types" set to *Yes* in the Document Set Library?

I have the same problem (Welcome Page disappearing) and I have allowed management of content types. When I set "Allow management of content types" to *No* the Welcome Page appears again.

EDIT: I fixed my problem - I had a folder-specific view set-up for a specific content type. I have now changed it so that I have a view for the "Top-level" Document Set and an "All" view for the rest of the folders. "Allow management of content types" is still set to *Yes* and the Welcome Page displays correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this doesn't help me. The strange thing is that only some of the documents sets show this behavior, not all!

Comment: Yes, mine is also just some and not others. The changing of view did not "really" solve my problem as now I can't use the views I want to (and the same views work on other places in the same site collection). It seems that the "zones" disappear on the page (there is only a "main"-zone). The actual web parts are still available to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that would occur when the document set folder's name was changed after it was created.

To be more specific, each document set that we have is a number representing a project number. When a new project came through a new document set would be created. If for whatever reason down the line the project number (and therefore the document set's name) would need to be changed, this sometimes would lose the welcome page.

So check that this does not occur for you when you change the document set's name.